# Basic drawing of a cuboid, one wall visible through another

Tags: opengl

Could someone explain to me *why* the following code, that's supposed to create front and bottom walls of a cuboid of dimensions (lx, ly, lz):

```
    // front
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glNormal3d(0, 0, 1);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, ly, lz);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, lz);
    gl.glVertex3d(lx, 0, lz);
    gl.glVertex3d(lx, ly, lz);
    gl.glEnd();
    // bottom
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glNormal3d(0, -1, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, lz);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(lx, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(lx, 0, lz);
    gl.glEnd();
```

Renders something like this:

[image: invalid cuboid]

Why is the bottom wall visible through the front wall? I've checked a 1000 times, and the vertices *are* in CCW order. They are, right?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have no depth buffer or depth testing disabled. Also a cuboid has 6 faces, while your code renders only two.

Comment: It's just a test for SO, that's why there are only two faces. You are totally right, depth testing was disabled. Thank you!